# Hazelcast 3.4 IQueue offer

Tags: hazelcast, nosuchmethoderror

In Hazelcast 3.4, I am getting a NoSuchMethodError exception from using IQueue offer with time parameters.  It works fine in Hazelcast 3.2. The code compiles and runs but when it executes the offer, it throws exception.

This is the method signature for BlockingQueue:

> public boolean offer(E e, long l, TimeUnit tu) throws InterruptedException;
>
> ```
> IQueue<GLBCSchema> queue=hzMQUtils.getQueue("myQueueName");
> ...
> GLBCSchema tmpMsg=new GLBCSchema();
> //queue.offer(tmpMsg);   <=== works!
> queue.offer(tmpMsg, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS); <== throws NoSuchMethodError
> ```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.hazelcast.core.IQueue.offer(Lgblx/gis/rtapi/facade/internal/GLBCSchema;JLjava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;)Z
```

This is a bug or has Hazelcast removed this offer method?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.  I figured it out.  After I removed the type declaration, it worked.

From:

```
IQueue<GLBCSchema> queue=hzMQUtils.getQueue("myQueueName");
```

To:

```
IQueue queue=hzMQUtils.getQueue("myQueueName");
```

I am not sure why they made this change. (Reference bug on JDK https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8064803)